# Using Kafka to Transfer Files between two clients

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have kafka cluster setup between to machines (machine#1 and machine#2) and the configuration is the following:

1) Each machine is configured to have one broker and one zookeeper running.
2) Server and zookeeper properties are configured to have a multi-broker, mulit-node zookeeper.

I currently have the following understanding of KafkaProducer and KafkaConsumer:

1) If I send a file from `machine#1` to `machine#2`, it's broken down in lines using some default delimiter (LF or \n).
2) Therefore, if machine#1 publishes 2 different files to the same topic, that doesn't mean that `machine#2` will receive the two files. Instead, every line will be appended to the topic log partitions and a `machine#2` will read it from the log partitions in the order of arrival. i.e. the order is not the same as

```
file1-line1
file1-line2
end-of-file1
file2-line1
file2-line2
end-of-file2
```

but it might be something like:
    file1-line1
    file2-line1
    file1-line2
    end-of-file1
    file-2-line2
    end-of-file2

Assuming that the above is correct (i'm happy to be wrong), I believe simple Producer Consumer usage to transfer files is not the correct approach (Probably connect API is the solution here). Since Kafka Website says that "Log Aggregation" is a very popular use case, I was wonder if someone has any example projects or website which demonstrates file exchange examples using Kafka.

**P.S.**  I know that by definition `Connect API` says that this is for reliable data exchange between kafka and "Other" systems - but I don't see why the other system cannot have kafka. So I am hoping that my question doesn't have to focus on "Other" non-kafka systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, however if u want the same order you can use just 1 partition for that topic.
So the order in which machine#2 reads will be the same as what you sent.
However this will be inefficient and will lack parallelism for which Kafka is widely used.

Kafka has ordering guarantee within a partition. quote from documentation

> Kafka only provides a total order over records within a partition, not
>   between different partitions in a topic

In order to send all the lines from a file to only one partition, send an additional key to the producer client which will hash the sent message to the same partition.
This will make sure you receive the events from one file in the same order on machine#2. If you have any questions feel free to ask, as we use Kafka for ordering guarantee of events generated from multiple sources in production which is basically your use case as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am actually working on a PoC which will possibly result in either transferring files from one kafka producer (`machine#1`) to others and vice-versa. So you are saying that I have to use connector API? or Do I need to use Stream instead?

Comment: @ha9u63ar If it is a two way transfer you have to run the same instance as producer as well as consumer connected to a kafka cluster. You can use connectors or simple Producer/Consumer client as well